# Converting hash values to either return 'true or false' whether it is a prime number

Tags: javascript

I have a module that has a dependency injection of a PrimeNumber module. I am insistent on keeping it this way in regard to the rest of my application which I have hidden from you, This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Pass return result of the count terms (hash) in as argument to primeNumber
2. Iterate over hash values to see if number is a prime or not by using function from PrimeNumber module
3. Add key 'prime to the hash' and value 'true or false'

To make things more visible to all of you. I have displayed what I am looking to achieve below:

```
 function Bananas(primenumber = new PrimeNumber) {
  this._primenumber = primenumber}

 Bananas.prototype.count = function(words) {
      return words.reduce((dict, v) => {dict[v] = v in dict ? dict[v] + 1 : 1; return dict}, {});

  }
```

The result of passing ["monkey", "monkey", "love", "banana", "banana"] to the above function would be `{ monkey: 2, love: 1, banana: 2 }`

I am trying to achieve the output of the function below:

```
 Bananas.prototype.primeNumber = function((Result of count)) {
      this._primenumber.isPrime(Result of count)
      return {monkey: 3, prime: true,
              elephant: 8, prime: false} <--- This is what I want to achieve
  }
```

PrimeNumber:

```
function PrimeNumber(){}

PrimeNumber.prototype.isPrime = function(num) {
  for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
  if(num % i === 0) return false
  return num !== 1
}

module.exports = PrimeNumber;
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: @Utkanos Look for the '<--- This is what I want to achieve' line.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to explain it the best I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate the keys and return an object with `prime` as new property

```
Bananas.prototype.primeNumber = function(countResult) {
  var self = this;
  return Object.keys(countResult).map( function(key){
      return { [key] : countResult[key], prime : self._primenumber.isPrime(countResult[key]) }
  });      
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. The problem is I am getting 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._primenumber.isPrime'

Comment: @monkeybanana did it worked? You have `this._primenumber` as the member variable of `Bananas` and this will be different inside the callback of `map`. I have updated the code. Please check.

Comment: My other method have access to 'this_primenumber.isPrime' however for some reason I am getting 'Cannot read property 'isPrime' of undefined' from your function

Comment: Sorry hold on, one second

Comment: I need to brush up on these skills :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve here:

**Input**:

```
{ monkey: 2, love: 1, banana: 2 }
```

**Output**:

```
[ { monkey: 2, prime: true }, { love: 1, prime: true }, { banana: 2, prime: true } ]
```

Because returning something like you mentioned in your question doesn't make sense. You can't duplicate keys in an object. So, for the changed one, the function can be written like this:

```
Bananas.prototype.primeNumber = function(counts) {
  return Object.keys(counts).map(function(key) {
    var result = {};
    result[key] = counts[key];
    result.prime = this._primenumber.isPrime(counts[key]);
    return result;
  });
}
```

It loops through the keys in the counts object, and for each key, it returns an object containing one additional key `prime`. I have assumed that the function `isPrime` works correct.